# Date Order in Cross Tab Query - use Separate Table to Sort

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, crosstab, ms-access-2016

I have a cross tab query with 'mmm-yyyy' formatted dates for Fields in the Columns.

I have used the below Design to create the query.

[Cross Tab Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOddw.jpg)

The problem I am having is the dates are not sorting correctly from Dec-17 down to Jul-16 in descending order. This is going to be a dynamic query with months changing every month so I want to use an additional table of data to do the sorting (as opposed to entering a list of month names in the Properties window).

[image: Month Order Table]

How would I fix my query to get it to do this please?

Thanks for your help

Comment: One option is to format the dates using a format that will sort correctly, like: `yyyy-mm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no matter how joined tables are sorted, crosstab will sort columns by default in alphabetical order, hence *Apr*, *Dec*, ... begins the order. To change or even filter column order in crosstabs, you would specify values in `PIVOT Col IN ()` clause of SQL statement.

Since you need a dynamic query consider creating a querydef in VBA to update the SQL behind the crosstab where you dynamically update the `PIVOT Col IN ()` clause. Of course, pass begin and end dates as needed or by parameters:

```vb
Public Sub BuildCrossTab() 
  Dim db As Database 
  Dim qdef As QueryDef 
  Dim strSQL As String, dates As String
  Dim i As Integer, monthsDiff As Integer

  Set db = CurrentDb

  ' DELETE PREVIOUS SAVED QUERY
  For Each qdef in db.QueryDefs
     If qdef.Name = "AccuralsCrosstabQ" Then
        db.Execute "DROP Table " & qdef.Name, dbFailOnError
     End If
  Next qdef

  ' LOOP THROUGH ALL MONTHS BACKWARDS 
  dates = "("
  monthsDiff = DateDiff("m", #7/1/2016#, #12/1/2016#)
  For i = monthsDiff To 0 Step -1
     dates = dates & " '" & Format(DateAdd("m", i, #7/1/2016#), "mmm-yyyy") & "',"
  Next i
  dates = dates & ")"
  dates = Replace(dates, ",)", ")")

  ' PREPARE SQL STRING 
  strSQL = "TRANSFORM SUM(a.[Amount $]) AS SumAmount" _ 
       & " SELECT a.Company, a.[Accrual ID], SUM(a.[Amount $]) As [Total Amount $]" _ 
       & " FROM [Accruals Raw Data] a " _ 
       & " GROUP BY a.Company, a.[Accrual ID]" _
       & " PIVOT Format(a.[Posted Date], ""mmm-yyyy"")" _
       & " IN " & dates

  ' CREATE QUERY
  Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("AccuralsCrosstabQ", strSQL)    

  Set qdef = Nothing 
  Set db = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait I will try this now.